# R Shiny: Align table and sortable bucket list

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to arrange the following outputs so that each number pair is aligned perfectly.

Is there a way to change the spacing of a table beyond the options avaible e.g `'l'`?

Following this, how could I vertically align the table with the `bucketlist`?

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(column(width =1,tableOutput("table")), column(width =1,
                                                              uiOutput("numbers"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table = renderTable( spacing = 'l',as.matrix(c(1:30)))
  
  
  output$numbers <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = h4("Numbers", align = "center"),
      group_name = "rank_Bedspace_Acuity",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      
      
      
      add_rank_list(
        text = h5("Numbers", align = "center",style="color: #fff; background-color: #4080C9"),
        input_id = "numbers",
        labels =  c(1:30)
      ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by vertical alignment? Do you want the table to appear right next to the sortable widget so that you get a reference between old table vs the updated one?

Comment: Indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacing of table - You will have to tweak the .css on your own.

I took your code and made the following updates to .css

Set *table*

`width: auto;` - Deleted this

`padding-top: 15px;` - Added this

`.tr { padding-bottom: 1px }`
(this is to match with the sortable height of 42px. Alternatively, you could also update the row height directly.

I assume by *vertical alignment*, you want the table to appear right next to the sortable widget so that you get a reference between old table vs the updated one. Applying the above .css tweaks, I get the following

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That's great, @FAlonso. Thanks very much.

Comment: Happy to help! :)